# Is there such a thing as a diminished unison?

Tags: intervals

I'm working through Mark Sarnecki's Rudiments of music theory book, and I'm digesting the bit about augmented and diminished intervals.

I'm confused as to how a **diminished unison** can exist.  By definition it would be one semi-tone smaller than a perfect unison, which cannot exist.

Am I missing some key idea somewhere?  Thanks so much!

**Edit:**  I don't believe the question is a duplicate, although it appears that way based only on the question headings.  I posit that when the question *bodies* are taken into account, the questions are distinct.

Comment: Even if the referred question seems to be somewhat different; what does the accepted answer not cover from your question?

Comment: Thanks for following up and giving me a chance to explain.  An expert can likely find the answer to this question within that answer.  But to a newbie like me, it seems to be talking about chords, not intervals.

Comment: The "duplicate" question refers to a diminished first (i.e. root) in a chord, rather than a diminished unison. There is nothing in the accepted answer that specifically spells out that there is no such thing as a diminished unison, although it does say that a half step written as a unison is always an augmented unison. I vote to reopen the question, as someone looking for the answer "no, there is no such thing as a diminished unison" would have a very tough time finding it in the other post.

Comment: I second @BobRodes. This question should be reopened. Though the answer to this question can be derived from the other question’s answer, the other question is not about this specific topic. I would even go as far as to say that the other question’s topic should be rewritten.

Comment: @CannedMan Interesting that the person who closed it is also the person who answered it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The unison is an exception to this due to how the unison works.

A perfect unison has a distance of 0 semitones from the original note while and augmented would have a distance of 1 semitones. Since the interval is perfect at a distance of zero one less would be -1 semitones,  but since most theorists only consider intervals as a positive number a diminished interval would be impossible.